# Routing API help (MapBox or similar)

Tags: geojson, routing, mapbox

I have a GeoJSON objects and I want to route between way-points on my GeoJSON file.

This is my example GeoJSON file:

```
{
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "generator":"JOSM",
  "bbox":[
    23.4668,
    58.9198,
    23.6412,
    58.974
  ],
  "features":[
    {
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":{
            "wheelchair":"yes",
            "smoothness":"bad",
            "surface":"crushed stones"
        },
        "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
                23.53359252,
                58.95034587858
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":{
            "wheelchair":"yes",
            "addr:housename":"Saue kohvik",
            "amenity":"pub",
            "name":"Saue kohvik"
        },
        "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
                23.5361382,
                58.9473236
            ]
        }
    },
     {
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":{
            "wheelchair":"yes",
            "smoothness":"intermediate",
            "highway":"footway"
        },
        "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[
                [
                    23.5410658,
                    58.9406213
                ],
                [
                    23.5410936,
                    58.9408252
                ],
                [
                    23.541092,
                    58.9408358
                ],
                [
                    23.5410706,
                    58.9410896
                ],
                [
                    23.5410448,
                    58.9412609
                ],
                [
                    23.541028,
                    58.9413309
                ],
                [
                    23.5409993,
                    58.9414512
                ],
                [
                    23.5408984,
                    58.9416477
                ],
                [
                    23.5408677,
                    58.9416962
                ],
                [
                    23.5407571,
                    58.9418706
                ],
                [
                    23.5405886,
                    58.9421204
                ],
                [
                    23.5405302,
                    58.9422071
                ],
                [
                    23.5403894,
                    58.9423888
                ],
                [
                    23.5401636,
                    58.9426413
                ],
                [
                    23.5400953,
                    58.9426593
                ],
                [
                    23.5399336,
                    58.9428447
                ],
                [
                    23.5399287,
                    58.9428504
                ],
                [
                    23.5399434,
                    58.9428895
                ],
                [
                    23.5394702,
                    58.9434341
                ],
                [
                    23.5394296,
                    58.943468
                ],
                [
                    23.5389324,
                    58.9439879
                ],
                [
                    23.5384256,
                    58.9445103
                ],
                [
                    23.5381597,
                    58.9447992
                ],
                [
                    23.5377425,
                    58.9452314
                ],
                [
                    23.5375449,
                    58.9454551
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
     {
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":{
            "wheelchair":"yes",
            "highway":"footway"
        },
        "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[
                [
                    23.5408677,
                    58.9416962
                ],
                [
                    23.541045,
                    58.9417267
                ],
                [
                    23.5412157,
                    58.9417564
                ]
            ]
        }
    }

    ]
}
```

And my question is: can I route between places inside my file, but the catch is: "routing only on these LineStrings where properties are "wheelchair":"yes" and "highway":"footway", and routing can't use LineStrings where property is only "highway":"footway".

Comment: I think this is far too broad a question to answer here, but here is a starting point: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#Developers -- also I would question the need to implement your own routing API when there are many others to look at first, e.g. pgRouting and Graphhopper -- for algorithms, look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Routing_algorithms, particularly Dijkstra's and A*

Comment: Thanks for answere and i read about graphopper. And now i have  next question witch is explaining why i aked  question about "making my own api" couse i dont know if existing api-s support my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

i asked about that and mapbox replay was:
We currently don't have a method to limit our walking directions to wheelchair="yes" paths. I would urge you to submit a feature request as an issue in this repo: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-directions.js. 
its done , so now i wait :)